Timestamp in oracle apex form
I have a form that I want to log the timestamp when submitted.
Here is my source for the page item CREATED_DATE_TIME.

And my DB column is set to timestamp(6).
And here is my rendered value on the form that I'm trying to pass.

But I'm getting the following error.

And I also tried this as localtimestamp:

But I get the following error.

And I cant really use a DB trigger as I will have several records being inserted from the form.
Example these 3 records should only have one d/t timestamp:


Check the globalization settings (Application Definition > Globalization). This will determine the format mask APEX uses when manipulating data of different flavours of type DATE.

The parameter "Application Timestamp Format" is referenced by the built-in substitution string APP_NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT. Use that substitution string as format mask for the default of the page item.

This worked fine for me. The page item is of type "Text" - for page items of type "Date" this format is not accepted.
